# Is pandas's `sample` with random_state guaranteed to be consistent for different variables?

Tags: python, pandas

The motivation for this question lies in the fact that I'd like randomly sample two pandas data structures in the same way. Let `X_train` be `pd.DataFrame` containing the feature vectors and `y_train` be a `pd.Series` containing the corresponding labels. I'm considering doing:

```
X_sample = X_train.sample(200, random_state=42)
y_sample = y_train.sample(200, random_state=42)
```

Of course, the two should be sampled in exactly the same way for it to work.

So the question is: for a fixed random_state and sample size, is `sample` methods on same-length `DataFrame`s and `Series`s guaranteed to be sampled in the same way?

Comment: While this may well be true, there really isn't any need for you to rely on this. Instead, create an array of indices first, and then use that array to index both dataframes. This will make your code both more robust and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is fixed YES (Dataframe index mainly the data itself and the sample size). random_state is used for reproducibility.